How to correctly import a PowerShell module with multiple class definitions
I have two PowerShell class definitions (File and Directory) and each class definition in a separate psm1 file:
File.psm1
class File
{
   [String]$Path
   
   File([String]$Path)
   {
      $this.Path = $Path
   }

}

Directory.psm1
using namespace System.Collections.Generic

using module .\File.psm1

class Directory
{
   [List[File]]$Files
   [String]$Path
   
   Directory([String]$Path)
   {
     $this.Path = $Path
     $this.Files = [List[File]]::new()
     if (Test-Path -Path $Path)
     {
        (Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -File).ForEach{
           $this.Files.Add([File]::new($_.FullName))
        }
     }
   }
}

So the directory class needs the definition of the file class.
I would like use the two classes inside a module Testmodule1.psm1.
The psm1 file Testmodule1.psm1 only contains a using module statement:
using module .\Directory.psm1

And the psd1 file Testmodule1.psd1 references Testmodule1.psm1 as the root module:
@{
  ModuleVersion = "0.0.1"
  RootModule = "TestModule1.psm1"
}

When I import the module like so:
import-module .\TestModule1.psd1 -Force -Verbose

the directory class is not known.
But when I load the module like it has been suggested by Michael Phillips here on SO, it works:
I have to import the module like so:
$m1 = import-module .\TestModule1.psd1 -Force -PassThru

and
& $m1 { [Directory]::new("G:\Skriptkiste") }

Now the Directory type is found.
I have tested this with Windows PowerShell and PowerShell 7.4.5.
My question is: Is there a cleaner way to achieve what I want?
I know this question had been the topic of many discussions on SO. But I can't believe that there is no simple and clean solution for the requirement of having multiple class definitions (with a "dependency") in PowerShell module.

Why do you want to be able to resolve the type literal [Directory] from outside TestModule? I believe there is indeed no good/simple/clean solution to this (PowerShell classes is not exactly the most complete feature of the language), but if you could describe the real-life problem that arises from this lack of type resolution maybe we can suggest alternative approaches.

There are modules dedicated to merge all dependencies into a single psm1 at build time. Aside from that as Mathias says, there is no cleaner way. PowerShell class support isnt good, if you like OOP write your module in c#.

Related: Is it possible to declare two interdependent classes each in a separate file?

I have a large PowerShell script that uses many classes. I am used from software development to put each class definition into a separate file. All the classes should be usable from other psm1 and ps1 files. That's the idea.

But of course as Mathias wrote its not really necessary

Building on the helpful comments:
The non-support for exporting class (and enum) definitions other than those placed directly in the root script module file (*.psm1) of a PowerShell module is a known limitation (as of PowerShell (Core) 7 v7.4.x, though a fix in the near future seems unlikely).
Quoting from the about_Using help topic; emphasis added:

The using module statement imports classes and enumerations from the root module (ModuleToProcess) of a script module or binary module. It doesn't consistently import classes or enumerations defined in nested modules or in scripts that are dot-sourced into the root module. Define classes and enumerations that you want to be available to users outside of the module directly in the root module.

As has been noted:

PowerShell's support for class definitions is incomplete and there are many feature requests and bug reports; GitHub issue #6652 is a meta issue that tracks them all (there has been little activity around these issues in quite some time as of this writing).

As a workaround - apart from putting all class and enum definitions directly in the root module, as shown below - you can employ a build tool, such as psake, in order to merge your distinct *.psm1 files into a single one that serve as the one referenced in the RootModule entry of your module manifest.



To spell it out:
Given your module manifest (TestModule.psd1) whose RootModule entry references TestModule.psm1, the latter's content must be as follows in order to make both [File] and [Directory] available to importers (who must use using module (rather than Import-Module / module autoloading) to import the module, as that is the fundamental prerequisite for seeing a module's class and enum definitions):
# Content of TestModule.psm1,
# which must *directly* contain the definitions of *both* [File] and [Directory].

using namespace System.Collections.Generic

class File
{
   [String]$Path
   
   File([String]$Path)
   {
      $this.Path = $Path
   }

}

class Directory
{
   [List[File]]$Files
   [String]$Path
   
   Directory([String]$Path)
   {
     $this.Path = $Path
     $this.Files = [List[File]]::new()
     if (Test-Path -Path $Path)
     {
        (Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -File).ForEach{
           $this.Files.Add([File]::new($_.FullName))
        }
     }
   }
}


I wanted to avoid having to put all class definitions in a single psm1 file. My "main" script contains a dozen class definitions and some of them contain functions with many commands so editing would be more effort.

@PeterM, that's understandable, so the best workaround it use a build tool that merges your separate file as part of a build process.
